# How to fix subscript out of range error when assigning named ranges to array using ListObjects?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign named range within my spreadsheet to an array.  I want to paste the same array value somewhere else.  Named range table has 3 columns and 59 rows but I want rows to be dynamic.

I tried other simpler ways to assigning it to array but, my focus is to do this dynamic array with ReDim array and using ListObjects and ListRow objects.

```
Dim vArray() As Variant

ReDim vArray(3,  Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("tblprices").ListRows.Count)

vArray = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("tblprices").DataBodyRange.Value

Range("F1").Select
Range("F:H").Value = vArray
```

The array should be copied into the array and pasted at the destination.  If someone can advise how to paste efficiently, then that would also be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I posted wrongly, it should say vArray at both places.   Yes both are vArray only.

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to copy the table and paste it in a contiguous range starting at cell F1. This would work even if the number of columns and/or rows change.

```
Dim vArray() As Variant, nRows As Long, nCols As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    nCols = .ListObjects("tblprices").ListColumns.Count
    nRows = .ListObjects("tblprices").ListRows.Count
    vArray() = .ListObjects("tblprices").Range.Value
    .Range(.Cells(1, 6), .Cells(nRows+1, 6+nCols-1)).Value = vArray
End With
```

Comment: Same error Subscript out of range on 3rd row.  nRows have 0 value.

Comment: @Jimmy check your spelling. That means you don't have a table with that name on that sheet.

Comment: It's there, I double checked tblPrices asssigned to A1toC59 within Sheet2.

Comment: Did you create this as a table (with Ctrl+T for example)? Or is it just a named range?

Comment: I tried this code again with nCols included again same error at line "nCols = .Listobjects...."

Comment: A `ListObject` is a table. If you're using a named range then you need `Range`.

Comment: I just want to use object ListObject.  How do i convert my data into table?

Comment: Use Ctrl+T or *Insert* > *Table*.

Comment: Thanks this is almost working. I am adding my data to table copying to the array and pasting to the different location but, it is not pasting the header row.

Comment: @Jimmy, when asking a question state what you want and are using. That's the only way your code can be amended easily without the *fun merry go rounds*. I have amended the code to include header rows